# Why Django REST Framework nested serializer self.instance always returns None?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have model,

```
class Profile(models.Model)
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

And my serializer classes are,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   def validate(self, attrs):
       print(self.instance) # Always prints None
       print(self.parent.instance.user) # Prints User instance
       return attrs

   class Meta:
       model = User

class ProfileSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
   user = UserSerializer()

   class Meta:
      Model = Profile
```

And my view class,

```
class ProfileView(APIView):
   def update(self, request):
      profile = ProfileSerializer(request.user.profile, data=request.data, partial=True)
      if profile.is_valid():
          profile.save()
          return Response(status=HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
      return Response({'error': profile.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Why `self.instance` inside `validate()` method in nested serializer always returns none?

Comment: you can access to class's attributes with self word key. but the UserSerializer do not have any attribute named instance.

Answer (score 1):

When do you see that? On creation?

In that case `self.instance` is populated inside the `save()` method with the result of `create()` method that's called after `validate().

[Here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#accessing-the-initial-data-and-instance) you can read

> When passing an initial object or queryset to a serializer instance, the object will be made available as .instance. If no initial object is passed then the .instance attribute will be None.

Comment: I've modified my question with my view method. It's on update.

Comment: As it a comment to your question, only the ProfileSerializer has `this.instance` populated but `UserSerializer` don't

Comment: How can I pass user instance to UserSerializer from ProfileSerializer?

Comment: the question is, why do you need it in the `validate` method? `validate` is supposed to be customize input data

Comment: Customize? I thought it was for validating input data. I need to verify old password at the time of password change. I've implemented that method in `validate`. To call `check_password`, I need to access user instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in a child serializer, you can access the instance using the `parent` field, instead the `instance` field, something like this:

```py
        if self.parent is not None and self.parent.instance is not None:
            instance = getattr(self.parent.instance, self.field_name)
            check_query = check_query.exclude(pk=user.pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem that you need to do that validation in the parent

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#updating-nested-serializers

> In the case of update operations on nested serializers there's no way of applying this exclusion, because the instance is not available.

> Again, you'll probably want to explicitly remove the validator from the serializer class, and write the code the for the validation constraint explicitly, in a .validate() method, or in the view.